# Getting background to fully cover android phone

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress

I am having some issues with my background only not loaded correctly on the android mobile screen. Works fine on apple. The styling I have used for the background is:

```
body
{

 background: url('images/MobileBack.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can also view the site at: www.bingetech.com

Answer (score 0):

i think it could be because you have not defined a scale within your viewport meta tag.

Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

[edited] with max-scale too

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Another thing i would add is

CSS

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you might need a max-scale too

Comment: added the updated with the max, seems to work a little bit better, but when I scroll or toggle between landscape and vertical views it doesn't render correctly

Comment: updated with max? or min? min would be more beneficial than max in this circumstances. You need to ensure that the containers that surround the container that has the bg image, and also set the bg image container to `height: 100%` are also set to `height:100%`too